# htaccess to redirect index.php without parameter

Tags: .htaccess, regex-negation

I am looking for the Redirect for .htaccess:

www.mydomain.com/A/ and www.mydomain.com/A/index.php without a parameter must be redirected to "www.mydomain.com/B/".

www.mydomain.com/A/index.php with a parameter like www.mydomain.com/A/index.php?id=123 is OK and must not be redirected.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **mod_rewrite**. You need to make sure that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled. Here is the rule for your URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^A/(index\.php)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/B/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

The rule will match both `/A/` and `/A/index.php` and will only redirect if query string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a redirect match for that

```
RedirectMatch "/A/index\.php$" http://www.mydomain.com/B
RedirectMatch "/A/$" http://www.mydomain.com/B
RedirectMatch "/A$" http://www.mydomain.com/B
```

I hope this will work :)

Comment: No -- he can not. RedirectMatch does not work with query string, so it will always be redirected, which is not what was requested.